# Mono Android Calendar control with Week view

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I need a Calendar Control with the week view capabilities that can be used for an Mono-Android project.

It should be able to support MMVMCross bindings as well. If it can be used with all the other 2 platform Windows Phone and iPhone, then it will be grate.

I have tried the Resco mobile tool kit( http://www.resco.net/mobileformstoolkit/ ). But I failed to cater my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is such a thing, so you will have to make it yourself or modify some component to do what you want.